# How do I use sturcturemap to pass two different implementations of a single interface into a constructor?

Tags: .net, structuremap, ioc-container

I have a constructor that take two interfaces, they are the same interface, but need to be different implementations:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IBar publicData, IBar privateData)
    {
    }
}
```

What I'd like to happen is that structuremap would pass in a concrete implementation of `IBar` as `class PublicData` and `class PrivateData` for the different arguments. Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

In fact, to make sure there is enough information:

The real classes that I'm working with look like this:

```
public abstract class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected EFRepository(IUnitOfWork publicUnitOfWork, 
                           IUnitOfWork privateUnitOfWork)
    {

    }
}
```

And an implementation of `EFRepository` might look like this:

```
public partial class ClaimRepository: EFRepository<Claim>, IClaimRepository
{
    public ClaimRepository(IUnitOfWork publishedUnitOfWork, 
                          IUnitOfWork unpublisedUnitOfWork) 
           : base(publishedUnitOfWork, unpublisedUnitOfWork)
    {
    }
}
```

So when I request and instance of `IClaimRepository` from structure map I want the implementation to be given the correct unit of work objects, which in my instance are essentially two different databases, so it's the same code with different connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't compiled and tested, but it should work in principle:

```
For<IBar>.Add<PublicData>.Named("public");
For<IBar>.Add<PrivateData>.Named("private");

For<IFoo>.Use<Foo>()
  .Ctor<IBar>("publicData").Is(d => d.TheInstanceNamed("public"))
  .Ctor<IBar>("privateData").Is(d => d.TheInstanceNamed("private"));
```

**Edit:** 
For making this by convention an `IRegistrationConvention` could be used

```
public class FooConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
  static readonly Type PluginType = typeof(IFoo);

  public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
  {
     if (type.IsAbstract || !type.IsClass || !PluginType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
       return;

      registry.For(PluginType).Add(type)
         .CtorDependency<IBar>("publicData")
         .IsNamedInstance("public")
         .CtorDependency<IBar>("privateData")
         .IsNamedInstance("private");
  }
}
```

The convention would be applied in a scan

```
Scan(scan => 
{
  scan.AssemblyContainingType<IFoo>();
  scan.Convention<FooConvention>();
}
```

See the [Scanning Assemblies section](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/ScanningAssemblies.htm) in the SM docs for further info.

Comment: Is there a way that this can be applied to a conventions based system? I'd rather not have to manually wire up all my repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the configuration as follows:

```
For<IFoo>.Use<Foo>();
For<IBar>.Use<IBar>();
```

Then get the instances as follows:

```
IBar privateData = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IBar>();
IBar publicData = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IBar>();

IFoo foo = ObjectFactory
    .With<IBar>(publicData)
    .With<IBar>(privateBar)
    .GetInstance<IFoo>();
```

This is just a suggestion. I stand corrected :-)